# Getting if username already exist in MYSQL database, Using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

So i have a MYSQL database and am making a register page for it, im trying to check to see if the username already exist in my database, Here is my code

```
                comd2 = conn.CreateCommand();
                comd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE username = @username ";
                comd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
                comd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                result = (int)comd2.ExecuteScalar();

                if (result > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("UserName already exsit");
```

The connection has already been established, i keep getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" i get this error on the result = (int)comd2.ExeuteScalar() line. i used something similar to this on my login form and it work perfectly but for some reason can't get it to work here. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ExecuteScalar with the COUNT sql function

```
comd2 = conn.CreateCommand();
comd2.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logininfo WHERE username = @username ";
comd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
result = Convert.ToInt32(comd2.ExecuteScalar());
if (result > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("UserName already exsit");
```

ExecuteNonQuery should not be used for SELECT query, while ExecuteScalar is appropriate when your query returns just one value. In your case you call a `SELECT *` that return all the data in the row (if the user exists) when you are just interested in knowing if an used with that user name exists or not. So asking to count the number of rows with that user name seems to be the correct choice

Comment: Ok i did that, now got a new error i need to try to work out lol

Comment: Specified cast is not valid, Its still stuck on the result

Comment: Yes, the problem is the cast requested from object (returned by ExecuteScalar) to int. Need to use Convert.ToInt32

Comment: Or you can just cast to `int?` instead of `int`

Comment: It is not a problem of null. The COUNT() will always return a value 0 or more records, not null. The problem is that you can't cast an object to an int because there is no explicit conversion. You need to Convert